# ionic3 Woocommerce https CORS error on iOS only

Tags: ionic3, woocommerce-rest-api

I don't know what they did with ionic 3 or angular 4 but pff...

My issue is that on Android it works, but on iOS device, I get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: Request header field password is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

This is the callers:

```
var optionsWoo = new HttpHeaders()
  //.set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  //.set("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .set("user", wp_key)
  .set("password", wp_sec)
  .set("Authorization", "Basic " + window.btoa(wp_key+":"+wp_sec));

this.http.get(site_url + 'wp-json/wc/v2/customers/' + id, {headers: optionsWoo}).toPromise()
        .then(usr => {
            return this.mergeUser(usr);
        }, err => {
            console.warn('errorS getUserAndMerge', err);
            return Promise.reject(err);
        });
```

I've built my app fist with:

```
 import {HTTP} from '@ionic-native/http'; - in app.module.ts
 import {Http} from "@angular/http"; - in Provider
```

Now I've moved to:

```
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";  - in app.module.ts
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http"; - in Provider
```

And using both packages with the ionic plugin:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-advanced-http" spec="^1.11.0" />
```

httpS authentification works with simply adding to the header as user/pass the API Key and Api Secret. Right?? I mean it's working from PostMan, and it's working on ANDROID!!! But on iOS I get the same f'ing error... been at this for 2 days now...

**ionic info**

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
ios-sim    : 5.0.11 
Node       : v8.9.3
npm        : 5.7.1 
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "myTitlte",
"version": "0.0.1",
"author": "Ionic Framework",
"homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
"private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.9",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/device-feedback": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/dialogs": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/zbar": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.4",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^1.11.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-cszbar": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-velda-devicefeedback": "0.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-select-searchable": "^1.0.9",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.7",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",
    "typescript": "2.7.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-cszbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-velda-devicefeedback": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-dialogs": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Just updated some of the main packages like `"@angular/common": "5.0.3",` and npm as well, but same thing...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding the wordpress secret and key as query params

```
var authQuery = '?username=' + wp_key + '&password=' + wp_sec;
this.http.post(site_url + 'wp-json/wc/v2/customers' + authQuery etc...
```